# How to optimize this Python code (from ThinkPython, Exercise 10.10)

Tags: python

I'm working through Allen Downey's *How To Think Like A Computer Scientist*, and I've written what I believe to be a functionally correct solution to Exercise 10.10.  But it took just over 10 hours (!) to run, so I'm wondering if I'm missing some really obvious and helpful optimization.

Here's the Exercise:

"Two words 'interlock' if taking alternating letters from each forms a new word.  For example, 'shoe' and 'cold' interlock to form 'schooled'.  Write a program that finds all pairs of words that interlock.  Hint: Don't enumerate all pairs!"

(For these word-list problems, Downey has supplied a file with 113809 words.  We may assume that these words are in a list, one word per item in the list.)

Here's my solution:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def index(lst, target):
    """If target is in list, returns the index of target; otherwise returns None"""
    i = bisect_left(lst, target)
    if i != len(lst) and lst[i] == target:
        return i
    else:
        return None

def interlock(str1, str2):
    "Takes two strings of equal length and 'interlocks' them."
    if len(str1) == len(str2):
        lst1 = list(str1)
        lst2 = list(str2)
        result = []
        for i in range(len(lst1)):
            result.append(lst1[i])
            result.append(lst2[i])
        return ''.join(result)
    else:
        return None

def interlockings(word_lst):
    """Checks each pair of equal-length words to see if their interlocking is a word; prints each successful pair and the total number of successful pairs."""
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, 12):  # 12 because max word length is 22
        # to shorten the loops, get a sublist of words of equal length
        sub_lst = filter(lambda(x): len(x) == i, word_lst)
        for word1 in sub_lst[:-1]:
            for word2 in sub_lst[sub_lst.index(word1)+1:]: # pair word1 only with words that come after word1
                word1word2 = interlock(word1, word2) # interlock word1 with word2
                word2word1 = interlock(word2, word1) # interlock word2 with word1
                if index(lst, word1word2): # check to see if word1word2 is actually a word
                    total += 1
                    print "Word 1: %s, Word 2: %s, Interlock: %s" % (word1, word2, word1word2)
                if index(lst, word2word1): # check to see if word2word1 is actually a word
                    total += 1
                    print "Word 2, %s, Word 1: %s, Interlock: %s" % (word2, word1, word2word1)
    print "Total interlockings: ", total
```

The print statements are not the problem; my program found only 652 such pairs.  The problem is the nested loops, right?  I mean, even though I'm looping over lists that contain only words of the same length, there are (for example) 21727 words of length 7, which means my program has to check over 400 million "interlockings" to see if they're actual words---and that's just for the length-7 words.

So again, this code took 10 hours to run (and found no pairs involving words of length 5 or greater, in case you were curious).  Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for any and all insight.  I'm aware that "premature optimization is the root of all evil"---and perhaps I've fallen into that trap already---but in general, while I can usually write code that runs correctly, I often struggle with writing code that runs well.

Comment: The answer below makes a lot of sense, but I'm interested if you tried profiling this code to identify what it is that actually makes it slow?

Other useful things to try for speedup are simply running it through Psyco or PyPy.

Comment: @Glenjamin: I haven't profiled the code because I don't know how.  Can you offer a link to some documentation explaining how to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html explains it far better than i can :)

Short version: `python -m cProfile myscript.py`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do it the other way around: Iterate through all words and split them into two words by taking the odd and even letters.  Then look up those two words in the dictionary.

As a side node, the two words that interlock must not necessarily have the same length -- the lengths might also differ by 1.

Some (untested) code:

```
words = set(line.strip() for line in open("words"))
for w in words:
    even, odd = w[::2], w[1::2]
    if even in words and odd in words:
        print even, odd
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try implementing that today and see if that helps.  Regarding your side note: I thought of that and decided it was too complicated for a first pass, and if I got the all-equal-length case working first, I'd go back and consider the differ-by-1 case as well.  Once I implement your suggestion successfully, I'll incorporate that twist into it.

Comment: Holy Moley!!  The elapsed time just went from 10 hours to 15.6 seconds.  And that's *including* the differ-by-1 case in the new implementation (which was trivial to implement).  Wow.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I think that this is the right approach but the incorrect result. ie, You are taking a single word and breaking it up into even and odd pieces of that single word. The problem stated is take TWO words and combined them into a single new word.

Comment: @drewk: The problem stated is: "Write a program that finds all pairs of words that interlock."  The code above does exactly this.

Comment: @drewk: If the list of all words only consists of "cold" and "shoe", then "schooled" is not a word by definition, and "cold" and "shoe" don't interlock.  The code above correctly does not print anything for this case.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate version:

```
with open('words.txt') as inf:
    words = set(wd.strip() for wd in inf)

word_gen = ((word, word[::2], word[1::2]) for word in words)
interlocked = [word for word,a,b in word_gen if a in words and b in words]
```

On my machine this runs in 0.16 seconds and returns 1254 words.

---

**Edit:** as pointed out by @John Machin at [Why is this program faster in Python than Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616847/why-is-this-program-faster-in-python-than-objective-c#5617487) this can be further improved by lazy execution (only perform the second slice if the first results in a valid word):

```
with open('words.txt') as inf:
    words = set(wd.strip() for wd in inf)
interlocked = [word for word in words if word[::2] in words and word[1::2] in words]
```

This drops execution time by a third, to 0.104 seconds.

Comment: This does not work. If `words` is `set(['cold', 'shoe'])` -- the OP example, `word_gen` is then [('cold', 'cl', 'od'), ('shoe', 'so', 'he')]

Comment: @drewk: If `words` was `set(['cold', 'shoe'])`, there would be no pair of interlocking words, and the above code wouldn't find any.  If `words` was `set(['cold', 'shoe', 'schooled'])`, there would be a pair of interlocking words, and the above code would find it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative definition for interlock:

```
import itertools

def interlock(str1, str2):
    "Takes two strings of equal length and 'interlocks' them."
    return ''.join(itertools.chain(*zip(str1, str2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>An important thing is your `index` function: It's the function that runs more than any function. When you don't need the index of the found word, why define a function to find that index?</s>

`if word1word2 in lst:` is enough instead of `if index(lst, word1word2):`.

The same for `if index(lst, word2word1):`.

OK. bisection works really faster than the `in` syntax. To improve the speed a bit more, i suggest using the `bisect_left` function directly in your `interlockings` function.

For example instead of:

```
        if index(lst, word1word2): # check to see if word1word2 is actually a word
            total += 1
            print "Word 1: %s, Word 2: %s, Interlock: %s" % (word1, word2, word1word2)
```

Use:

```
        q = bisect_left(lst, word1word2)
        if q != len(lst) and lst[q] == word1word2:
            total += 1
            print "Word 1: %s, Word 2: %s, Interlock: %s" % (word1, word2, word1word2)
```

A very slight improvement in speed.

Comment: Downey suggests earlier in the book that the "item in list" syntax runs more slowly than a bisection algorithm, which my "index" function uses.  I confess I haven't tested his assertion to see if my index function actually runs faster than the built-in "in" syntax, so perhaps I'll test that later.

Comment: @Alex: You are right about that your `index()` function is faster than Hossein's suggestion `word in lst`.  Even faster than both of those is to use a `s = set(words)` and test `word in s`.