# Why do these two implementations produce different results?

Tags: python

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5523058/115543) and got an excellent answer (thanks!).  Part of the problem to be solved involved taking a word and de-interlacing it, so that you get two words, one containing the even-indexed characters of the original word, the other containing the odd-indexed characters.

The responder used the following code to do this:

```
for w in words:
    even, odd = w[::2], w[1::2]
```

I did it this (worse) way:

```
for w in words:
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    for c in w:
        if w.index(c) % 2 == 0:
            lst1.append(c)
        else:
            lst2.append(c)
    even = ''.join(lst1)
    odd = ''.join(lst2)
```

Okay, my way is worse for a number of reasons.  But it seems to me as though both ways should at least produce the same pairs of words.  And yet, I get different results using his implementation than mine.  Why is that?

Comment: Quoting a pair of actual results at the Python prompt would make the question a bit quicker for people to answer. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `index(c)` asks the index of the *first* occurrance of the letter in the word — so you are creating a single “bucket” for each letter. So if the first `'a'` is odd, then *all* of the `'a'` letters also get stuffed into the "odd" string. To fix this, you should just use `enumerate()` to count:

```
for i, c in enumerate(word):
    # check whether ``i`` is even/odd, etc
```

Comment: That explains a lot, actually.  Thanks!